# How to retrieve empty values stored in database?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I am using Sqlite database and storing empty values for rows.I am using this code for storing empty values in the database:

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME,"");
            values.put(KEY_PH_NO,"");           
            values.put(KEY_FOLDER_NAME, contact.getFolderName());
            values.put(KEY_FolderAddress, contact.getParentFolderAddress());
            values.put(KEY_TIME, contact.getTime());    
            values.put(KEY_DATE, contact.getDate());
```

And i am using following query to retrieve the database entry having empty values:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE "+KEY_FolderAddress+" ='"
                     +FileAddress+"'"+" AND "+KEY_FOLDER_NAME+" ='"+FileName+"'"+" AND "+KEY_DATE+" ='"+"0"+"'"
                     +" AND "+KEY_PH_NO+" ='"+""+"'"+" AND "+KEY_NAME+" ='"+""+"'";
```

But i am getting this exception while retrieving empty values:

```
12-25 11:52:40.531: E/Exception:(1990): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM rules WHERE folderaddress ='/sdcard/Velosys/a' AND folder_name ='a' AND date ='0' AND phone_number ='' AND name ='' Exception occured in getTimeOfTheFolderFromContact() of DatabaseHandlerRule.java
```

I have searched a lot but did not get the solution.Please help me in finding the right way to retrieve empty values from sqlite database.Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
I am storing 2 entries with empty values i.e KEY_NAME and KEY_PH_NO
```

This is the table format:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "+ KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT, "
            +KEY_FOLDER_NAME+" TEXT, "+ KEY_FolderAddress + " TEXT, "+KEY_TIME + " TEXT, "+KEY_DATE+" TEXT "+")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

Comment: Did you try to execute this query in sqlite query browser?

Comment: No sir,in my app in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use some common value to store in database:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME,"null");
            values.put(KEY_PH_NO,"null");
```

Please use this code to retrieve null values:
Yes you are right because the "null" value will be stored as a string value in database.

```
int i = resultSet.getInt(resultSet.getColumnIndex(columnName));
        String str = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex(columnName));
        boolean bool = resultSet.isNull(resultSet.getColumnIndex(columnName));
        if( str == null )
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return i;
```

Comment: And can you please tell me what should be the query to retrieve null values. Is this right:    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE "+KEY_FolderAddress+" ='"
   +FileAddress+"'"+" AND "+KEY_FOLDER_NAME+" ='"+FileName+"'" +" AND "+KEY_DATE+" ='"+"0"+"'"+" AND "+KEY_NAME+" ='"+"null"+"'"
   +" AND "+KEY_PH_NO+" ='"+"null"+"'";

Answer (score 1):

For insert Any value your way of method is correct.
for Example:

```
public boolean insertSample() {
    boolean success = false;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, "");
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, "");
    values.put(KEY_FOLDER_NAME, "foldername");
    values.put(KEY_FolderAddress, "folderAddress");
    values.put(KEY_TIME, "anytime");
    values.put(KEY_DATE, "date");

    long id = database.insert(TABLE_SAMPLe_DETAIL, null, values);

    success = id > 0;

    return success;
}
```

For Retrieving u can use like this.

```
public Cursor getAllSample(String fileAddress, String fileName,
        String keyDate, String keyPhone, String keyName) {

    String whereClause = KEY_FolderAddress + "=? AND " + KEY_FOLDER_NAME
            + " =? AND " + KEY_DATE + " =? AND " + KEY_PH_NO + " =? AND "
            + KEY_NAME + " =?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(fileAddress),
            String.valueOf(fileName), String.valueOf(keyDate),
            String.valueOf(keyPhone), String.valueOf(keyName) };

    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_SAMPLe_DETAIL, null, whereClause, whereArgs,
            null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Your Query is correct");
    }

    return cursor;
}
```

You can call this method as :
getAllSample("folderAddress", "foldername", "date", "", "");

Where database is object of SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

try to save this two value as String

```
        values.put(KEY_TIME, contact.getTime());    
        values.put(KEY_DATE, contact.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Before run each sql query is best to run it on Sqliteman or any sqlite query browser, this has two advantages:

1- you see your syntax error and can fix them.

2- you know column's default value of the table

therefore if null stored in the column you can use "IS NULL" in your where clause of query.